# How to use ICLRStrongName::StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx Method to identify delay signed assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Can anybody please suggest how to use **ICLRStrongName::StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx** method to identify delay signed assembly. I could not find any example in the internet. I am not understanding how to work with this method.

Please don't refer me any link, I am almost frustrated with different suggestions and different links available in the web. Can anybody please give code sample for the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally found the time to investigate. I really don't understand why Microsoft did not take the time to write an adequate documentation.

Following link is very helpful and also contains a sample project, even if it also doesn't answer all questions: http://clractivation.codeplex.com/

I'll try to answer all questions with a short code sample. You could use something like this to verify a assembly's strong name:

```
public bool VerifyStrongName(string assemblyPath, bool force)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyPath))
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Empty, "assemblyPath");

  var host = HostingInteropHelper.GetClrMetaHost<IClrMetaHost>();

  var bufferSize = 100;
  var version = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
  var result = host.GetVersionFromFile(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, version, ref bufferSize);
  if ((HResult)result != HResult.S_OK)
    throw new COMException("Error", result);

  IClrRuntimeInfo info = host.GetRuntime(version.ToString(), new Guid(IID.IClrRuntimeInfo)) as IClrRuntimeInfo;
  ICLRStrongName sn = info.GetInterface(new Guid(CLSID.ClrStrongName), new Guid(IID.IClrStrongName)) as ICLRStrongName;

  var verResult = sn.StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(assemblyPath, Convert.ToByte(force));
  return Convert.ToBoolean(verResult);
}
```

You can find all classed and interfaces used in this sample in the **ClrActivation** sample project.

Additionaly I changed the **HRESULT** class to be an enum...

```
  /// <summary>
  /// A set of common, useful HRESULTS, and related functionality
  /// </summary>
  public enum HResult
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// OK/true/Success
    /// </summary>
    S_OK = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// False
    /// </summary>
    S_FALSE = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// The method is not implemented
    /// </summary>
    E_NOTIMPL = unchecked((int)0x80004001),
    /// <summary>
    /// The interface is not supported
    /// </summary>
    E_NOINTERFACE = unchecked((int)0x80004002),
    /// <summary>
    /// Bad Pointer
    /// </summary>
    E_POINTER = unchecked((int)0x8004003),
    /// <summary>
    /// General failure HRESULT
    /// </summary>
    E_FAIL = unchecked((int)0x8004005),
    /// <summary>
    /// Invalid Argument
    /// </summary>
    E_INVALIDARG = unchecked((int)0x80070057),
    /// <summary>
    /// Insufficient buffer
    /// </summary>
    ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = unchecked((int)0x8007007A),
    /// <summary>
    /// HRESULT for failure to find or load an appropriate runtime
    /// </summary>
    CLR_E_SHIM_RUNTIMELOAD = unchecked((int)0x80131700),

    SEVERITY = unchecked((int)0x80000000)
  }
```

...and added the static classed **CLSID** and **IID** (took me some time to find the correct CLSID):

```
  public static class IID
  {
    public const string IClrRuntimeInfo = "BD39D1D2-BA2F-486A-89B0-B4B0CB466891";
    public const string IClrMetaHost = "D332DB9E-B9B3-4125-8207-A14884F53216";
    public const string IClrStrongName = "9FD93CCF-3280-4391-B3A9-96E1CDE77C8D";
    public const string IEnumUnknown = "00000100-0000-0000-C000-000000000046";
  }

  public static class CLSID
  {
    public const string ClrStrongName = "B79B0ACD-F5CD-409b-B5A5-A16244610B92";
  }
```

I hope I could help you. If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I am getting red squiggly line under the line: var host = HostingInteropHelper.GetClrMetaHost<IClrMetaHost>();. I am not understanding how to call static calss method from my method. I have posted my code at: http://www.4shared.com/zip/OsI5deh-ce/TestDelaySign.html. Can you suggest me the solution as it is very urgent for me. MY ULTIMATE GOAL IS TO RETURN TRUE FOR DELAY SIGNED ASSEMBLY.

Comment: The first problem in your solution is, that the class HostingInteropHelper is not marked as public (that's also exactly what the error message tells). Mark it as public and you won't have this problem. Next is, that you can only use my code, if you use all my code (replace the static class HResult with my enum above, or you won't be able to cast the result). You will also need to include the static classes CLSID and IID (see above) or just paste the corresponding GUIDs. Further you forgot some using directives (System.Reflection and System.Runtime.InteropServices). Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems I have almost completed except the below error.
Program.cs(8,33): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Runtime.Hosting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Unfortunately, I don't know how to work with Interop and I could not get proper resources in the net. Request you to help me on this.

Comment: Looks like this is part of a namespace contained in the ClrActivation Assemblies. Did you reference both projects? When I tested it there were no more errors after applying the changes mentioned above. If this does not help, just upload your current solution so I can check it for you.

Comment: Hi tY Software,
Sorry for the late reply. I am on vacaction and could not concentrate on this work. I have uploaded my code to the following URL.
http://www.4shared.com/zip/q8MTfzeoce/TestDelaySign.html
To reproduce this error, use VS Command prompt to compile Program.cs file: csc Program.cs
I am getting the following error:

Program.cs(8,33): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Runtime.Hosting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: ? Why do you try to compile Program.cs only? Please build the whole solution (Solution Explorer -> right click on the solution item -> build solution) and it will work. I had no problems compiling it.

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention that I don't think this method will have the effect you expect at all. I never worked with delay signed assemblies but don't think they will be accepted as signed since they don't have a valid strong name.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Does this method work for you? Plesse share your experience (and accept my answer if it was helpful, so it can help other people having the same problem).

Comment: I should tell dozens of thanks for your effort to solve my issue, but unfortunately your answer DID-NOT work for me.  Since it is so urgent requirement for me, I have changed the entire style of my application design and solved the problem. In my new program, I am not checking if the passed-in parameter is delay-signed assembly or not. I am right-away doing re-sign for every assembly. What happens is that strongly signed assemblies will be re-signed once again, which is not at-all a problem for my architect(he agreed for my proposal) :-)