# StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx: DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, pinvoke, strongname

When I'm calling this method, I get a DllNotFoundException which is telling me, that mscorsn.dll could not be found. 
However the library is there and I don't know what the problem is.
Does anybody know this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, `DllNotFoundException` is pretty clear cut. Either the DLL you p/invoke, or one of its dependencies, cannot be found. Unless you provide more details, we are all just going to have to guess as to the reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What kind of details do you mean? I'm using .net 4.5 (also tested with previous versions), tested it on 2 machines (same result) and the dll which can not be found is there (included in .net). Unfortunately I don't know what else to say.

Comment: Well, you didn't show any code, so for all we know you got the name wrong. More likely the DLL is not in the search path. One wonders why you use the deprecated function instead of the supported method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff844054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I managed to solve it. The problem was, that I tried to import mscorsn.dll while I should have imported mscoree.dll. I use this function at the moment, because the new one seems not well documented, so I did not manage to use it (with C#) in time. I also found many people having the same problem (and not getting an answer), so I decided to use the old one until I find enough time to investigate. If you know how to use it I'd appreciate if you would share this knowledge.

Comment: Ok, I took the time to investigate and found a solution (even if it could have been easier): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754960/how-to-use-iclrstrongnamestrongnamesignatureverificationex-method-to-identify/21854403#21854403 Thanks four your suggestions. You helped me a lot.