# Programmatically verify digital signature of .exe in C#

Tags: c#, dll, exe, digital-signature

within the C# code of my .dll I want to verify the digital signature of the .exe that is calling my .dll. I am looking for a way to do something like `SignTool Verify [...]` from code.

The digital signature I want to check is displayed on the digital signature tab in the windows file explorer. As an example, here is an example screenshot of this tab.

[image]

How do I access the digital signature of the .exe from C# code? What is the best way to do this? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: How is the DLL signed - using a code signing certificate, or by using a signing key (`AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile`)?

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754960/how-to-use-iclrstrongnamestrongnamesignatureverificationex-method-to-identify

Comment: what I want to check is the digital signature of the .exe file that is also listed in the digital signature tab in file explorer (I added a screenshot to the original question). I do not have any details about the calling .exe / assembly as it is written by someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I use reflection to compare the cert.
Sample like below:

```
string dllPath = "";
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
var modules = assembly.GetModules();
var cert = modules[0].GetSignerCertificate();
```